# Changing two states sequentially throws an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing an experiment where once an event is triggered, it would remove the dot at the end of the input string if ever one exist; otherwise, return the whole string as the value for `this.state.output`.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
      input: null,
      output: null
    }

    generateString = (e) => {
      this.setState({
        input: e.target.value
      })  
    }

    removeEndDot = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const removedDot = /[\.]$/.test(this.state.input) ?
                         this.state.input.slice(0, this.state.input.length - 1).join('') :
                         this.state.input;

      this.setState({
        input: null,
        output: removedDot
      })
    }

    render() {
      const divStyle = {
        border: '1px solid #5f5f5f',
        padding: '0.5rem',
        flex: '1'
      };

      return(
        <div>
          <form action="" onSubmit={this.removeEndDot}>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.generateString} />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
          </form>
          <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
            <div style={divStyle}>{this.state.input}</div>
            <div style={divStyle}>{this.state.output}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

The problem is whenever I type an input string with an end-dot, it throws an error that says:

> _this.state.input.slice(...).join is not a function

I tried to do this instead because I thought I was changing states synchronously, but didn't work as well:

```
this.setState({
  output: removedDot
}, () => {
    this.setState({
      input: null
    })
})
```

(Please bear with me for creating two states instead of only one to make it easy. I have my own reason why I created two states; besides, it's just an experiment.)

Comment: `.slice` gives string. Why do you want to `join()`? Remove the `.join()`. `this.state.input` is a string, and applying `.slice()` on it, will give another string. So no need `.join(..)` here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `join()` is being called on a `String` as opposed to on an `Array`.

---

Let's assume

```
this.state.input = 'foo.';
```

Then you'd call

```
state.input.slice(0, state.input.length - 1).join();
```

The first part, `state.input.slice(0, state.input.length - 1)`, is fine, it would return `'foo'`. However, `'foo'.join()` won't work.

```js
const correctUsage = ['f', 'o', 'o'].join('');

console.log('correct usage ---->');
console.log(correctUsage);

try {
  const incorrectUsage = 'foo'.join('');
} catch(e) { 
  console.log('incorrect usage --->');
  console.error(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Very much appreciated :)

Comment: I didn't know `.slice()` can also be used for strings. My bad

Comment: glad to help! if an answer does answer your question, you can accept it by clicking the "check" icon

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use the function `.join("")` on a string. This method works for array's but not for strings. Try using `.substring()` instead